# ES6 arrow function - find the most frequent item in an array

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, arr

I need to create a very, very lean ES6 arrow function that consoles out the most frequent name in my array....

```
function mostFrequent(arr){

};
```

**// Example usage**

```
let names = ['Jack', 'Anthony', 'Richy', 'Jane', 'Karen', 'Jane', 'Mary', 'Jane' ];

console.log('The most frequently used name is', mostFrequent(names));
```

Answer (score 2):

**ES6** function to find the most frequent item in an array:

```js
let names = ['Jack', 'Anthony', 'Richy', 'Jane', 'Karen', 'Jane', 'Mary', 'Jane'];

function mostFrequent(arr) {
    return arr.sort((x, y) =>
        arr.filter(e => e === x).length -
        arr.filter(e => e === y).length
    ).pop();
}
console.log(`The most frequently used name is '${mostFrequent(names)}'`);
```